# AsyncStorage чтение внутри функционального компонента - React Native

Tags: функции, react-native, react-hook, jsx

Как значение с одной страницы можно передать на другую (для применения настроек в приложении, к примеру)?

Наткнулся на AsyncStorage. Пытаюсь его применить + прочитать в консоли, но выходит всегда такая ошибка, при переключении switch. Понимаю, что наверное надо вызывать `try { await` и т.д., но не пойму, как в компоненте обращаться к нему.

Redux не применяю, страницы реализованы через react-navigation.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Platform, AsyncStorageStatic } from 'react-native';
    import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
    import { stylebg } from '../styles/Styles';
    import { gstyles } from '../styles/Styles';
    import { Bgurl } from '../styles/Styles';
    import SwitchSelector from "react-native-switch-selector";
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    export default function Settings({navigation}) {
        const LoadScene = () => {
            navigation.navigate('Main');
        }
        const [switchValue, setSwitchValue] = useState('0');
        const toggleSwitch = (options) => {
            setSwitchValue(options);
            let value = switchValue;
            AsyncStorage.setItem('Bar', value);
            console.log (AsyncStorage.getItem('Bar'));
        };
        const options = [
            { label: "OFF", value: '0' },
            { label: "ON", value: '1' }
        ];
        

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            return (
                <ImageBackground blurRadius={15} source={Bgurl} resizeMode="cover" style={stylebg.image}>
                    <View style={gstyles.SettingsFirst}>

                        <View>
                            <StatusBar 
                                barStyle={'dark-content'} //light-content or dark-content
                                hidden={AsyncStorage.getItem('Bar') === '1' ? 'false' : 'true'}
                            />
                        </View>

                        <View style={gstyles.SettingsAllWithoutSave}>

                            <View style={switchValue ? gstyles.ViewStatusBarON : gstyles.ViewStatusBarOFF}>

                                <Text style={gstyles.textInSettingsTitle}>Settings</Text>

                                <Text style={gstyles.textStatusBarTurn}>
                                    {switchValue ? 'Status Bar' : 'Status Bar'}
                                </Text>

                                <View style={gstyles.switch}>
                                    <SwitchSelector style={gstyles.switchStatusBar}
                                        onPress={toggleSwitch}
                                        options={options}
                                        initial={0}
                                        selectedColor={'black'}
                                        buttonColor={'white'}
                                        backgroundColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}
                                        textColor={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'}
                                        fontSize={18}
                                        textStyle={gstyles.switchText}
                                        selectedTextStyle={gstyles.switchTextSelected}
                                        animationDuration={200}
                                    />
                                </View>

                            </View>

                        </View>

                        <View style={gstyles.centrIOSSett}></View>

                        <View style={gstyles.aroundbuttonSaveSettings}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={gstyles.ButtonInSettingSave} onPress={LoadScene}>
                                <Text style={gstyles.ButtonInSettingSaveText}>Save</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            );
        }
        else {
            //Тут тоже самое, но для Android
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((response) => {console.log(response)});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/724385)